# msbuild community task and svn

Tags: svn, msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

I try use svn msbuild community tasks?

```
<SvnCopy SourcePath="$(TrunkPath)" DestinationPath="$(TagPath)" Message="AutoBuild: create tag for build" />
```

but have next error in log:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.237]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 30.11.2011 13:16:37.
Project "d:\repository\FusionEnterprise\FusionWebServices\trunk\WebServicesSetu
p.msbuild" on node 1 (CreateSvnTag target(s)).
CreateSvnTag:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN\bin\svn.exe copy "..\trunk" "..\tags\7.3.2.9
  " --message "AutoBuild: create tag for build" --non-interactive --no-
  auth-cache
  svn: E205009: Local, non-commit operations do not take a log message or revis
  ion properties
d:\repository\FusionEnterprise\FusionWebServices\trunk\WebServicesSetup.msbuild
(104,5): error MSB6006: "svn.exe" exited with code 1.
Done Building Project "d:\repository\FusionEnterprise\FusionWebServices\trunk\W
ebServicesSetup.msbuild" (CreateSvnTag target(s)) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"d:\repository\FusionEnterprise\FusionWebServices\trunk\WebServicesSetup.msbuil
d" (CreateSvnTag target) (1) ->
(CreateSvnTag target) ->
  d:\repository\FusionEnterprise\FusionWebServices\trunk\WebServicesSetup.msbui
ld(104,5): error MSB6006: "svn.exe" exited with code 1.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.20
```

There used VisualSVN command line applicatin.

But when I write in console: `svn --version`, get next output

```
svn, version 1.7.1-SlikSvn-1.7.1-X64 (SlikSvn/1.7.1) X64
   compiled Oct 26 2011, 14:18:24
```

There used SlikSvn command line application.

```
Path=%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN\bin
```

I try use next msbuild task:

```
<SvnCopy SourcePath="$(TrunkPath)" DestinationPath="$(TagPath)" Message="AutoBuild: create tag for build" ToolPath="C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svn.exe" />
```

and

```
<SvnCopy SourcePath="$(TrunkPath)" DestinationPath="$(TagPath)" Message="AutoBuild: create tag for build" ToolPath="C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin" />
```

But it's work incorrect.

I don't understand how set right svn application for msbuild and can't find this informatin in google.
Is anybody can clarify this?

Added:
If use task `<SvnCopy SourcePath="$(TrunkPath)" DestinationPath="$(TagPath)" />` VisualSVN work right.

Answer (score 3):

Your `$(TagPath)` = `"..\tags\7.3.2.9"` indicates that this is a local path. And this is what your error message is saying:

> svn: E205009: Local, non-commit operations do not take a log message or revision properties

That means for local copies which is not a commit action a log message is useless.

If you want to tag your build within repository you need to provide a repository path as your `$(TagPath)` something like `file:///C:/repositories/myapp/tags/7.3.2.9` or something similar starting with `svn://...` or `http://....` depending on your checkout.